# How can I use a case statement that includes a wildcard

Tags: sql, tsqlt

I have tried to include a wildcard in the below Case statement with no good result.

```
CASE 
    WHEN store IS NULL THEN
        (
            CASE
                WHEN location IN (‘A%’, ‘B%’’ ‘C%’) THEN ‘staff’ 
                ELSE store_code
        ) 
    ELSE store
    END AS sister_store
```

Comment: If you have a lot of wildcards, you can create a small lookup table with those wildcards and do a left join. Then use case a statement to handle match vs no match

Answer (score 2):

If the part preceding the wildcard is only one letter as in your example, then

`CASE WHEN location like '[ABC]%' then`

The particular syntax you are looking for is actually `LIKE ANY` (supported at least by Teradata but not by SqlServer afaik.

If the check is more complex you should split it into OR parts, like:

`CASE WHEN location like 'A%' or location like 'B%' or location like 'C%' then`

You can also use CHARINDEX/PATINDEX functions for more elaborate conditions.